# R ggplot2: Can't change the names of the values in x axis without ruining the graph

Tags: r

Asssume this is the dataset:

```
n   value
100000  20
200000  30
300000  25
400000  40
500000  12
```

Here is the code that creates the plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
data <- read.table("test", sep = "\t", header = TRUE,)
ggplot(data, aes(n, value)) + 
geom_point(aes(n,value)) + geom_line(aes(n,value)) + ylim(0,60)+ 
dev.off()
```

[image]

I would like to make the values on the x axis be like this: 100k, 200k, 300k, 400k, 500k. I have tried the following code:

```
require(ggplot2)
data <- read.table("test", sep = "\t", header = TRUE,)
ggplot(data, aes(n, value)) + 
geom_point(aes(n,value)) + 
geom_line(aes(n,value)) + 
ylim(0,60)+
scale_x_discrete(limit=c(100000,200000,300000,400000,500000), 
labels=c("100k","200k","300k","400k","500k"))
dev.off()
```

The values of the x axis change nicely, but the left most point can barely be seen, same for the right most point:

[image]

Is it possible to fix this problem? I would like the graph to look like in the first picture but only with the names on the axis axis changed. Note that this is a small dataset, so I could probably change the values inside the dataset by hand, my actual dataset is very large which makes this approach impossible.

Comment: If you don't want to have to write out the labels each time, you could use `unit_format` from package *scales*.  `scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(unit = "K", scale = 1/1000, sep = ""))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scale_x_continuous`, not `scale_x_discrete`:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(limits = c(100000, 500000),
                     labels = c("100k","200k","300k","400k","500k"))
```